# Convert shell script command to command line

Tags: python, shell, sh

I am executing python script with multiple command line parameter, but using shell script.

command i execute for shell script execution is:

```
./scripts/run_qa.sh data/questions/questions.txt data/lexicons/paralex data/weights/paralex.txt data/database > output.txt
```

run_qa.sh files looks like below (please explain how it works):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -u
set -e
if [ $# != 4 ]; then
    echo "Usage: run.sh questions lexicon weights db"
    exit 1
fi
questions=$1
lexicon=$2
weights=$3
db=$4
PYTHONPATH=$PWD/python python -m lex.gearman_worker $lexicon $weights $db < $questions
```

I tried to execute python command as below in **Command line** :

```
python -m python/lex/gearman_worker.py data/lexicons/paralex data/weights/paralex.txt data/database > output.txt
```

which gives error :

```
/usr/bin/python: Import by filename is not supported.
```

Update1 :

gearman_worker.py file import other files like ths:

```
import lex.parse
import lex.semantics
from collections import namedtuple
from collections import defaultdict
```

import line gives error like this:

```
ImportError: No module named lex.lexicon
```

Update2 (executed on linux terminal):

```
export PYTHONPATH=$/mnt/paralex-evaluation-gearman/python
PYTHONPATH = ./python python -m python/lex/gearman_worker data/lexicons/paralex data/weights/paralex.txt data/database > output.txt
```

gives:

```
PYTHONPATH: command not found
```

Then

```
python -m python/lex/gearman_worker data/lexicons/paralex data/weights/paralex.txt data/database > output.txt
```

gives:

```
File "/mnt/paralex-evaluation-gearman/python/lex/gearman_worker.py", line 3, in <module>
    import lex.lexicon
ImportError: No module named lex.lexicon
```

Comment: @mu無: sorry, updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to execute the following command:

```
PYTHONPATH=./python python -m lex.gearman_worker ARGUMENT_2 ARGUMENT_3 ARGUMENT_4 < ARGUMENT_1
```

If that doesn't work then you may have to export the `PYTHONPATH` setting:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PWD}/python
python -m lex.gearman_worker ARGUMENT_2 ARGUMENT_3 ARGUMENT_4 < ARGUMENT_1
```

The original arguments that you would pass to the script are listed as `ARGUMENT_N`.

The script just:

- sets some sensible defaults (see [the documentation for set](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin))
- tests the the right number of arguments have been supplied
- invokes the command above

Your attempt to invoke it:

- misses the `PYTHONPATH` setting which is present in the script
- passes the gearman_worker module as a file rather than a python module import

Comment: Done that. You were close.

Comment: I dont want to use shell script, i want to execute command directly from terminal. I could not do it, can you please help for that

Comment: Yes. Look at the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: I already tried it, gives error `PYTHONPATH: command not found`

Comment: What shell are you using? The command I supplied works fine in `bash`, which is the shell that your original script uses.

Comment: thanks, but still facing issue, I am using linux terminal to execute this command. I am already using `bash` file as in initially question, but want to migrate on python execution from terminal. Please check **Update2** in question

Comment: Please read the answer I have provided. `PYTHONPATH = ` does not appear within it.

Comment: Seriously. Read my answer. Do what it says. The commands you are executing are different. No wonder they fail.

Comment: Sorry man : ). thanks by the way for your passion. I required 15 points to upvote your answer, which I dont have

Comment: Sorry if I offended you! The fact is, different languages have different rules. One of the odd things about shell scripting is that whitespace matters a lot more than you expect. The bashref link I provided (documentation for set) covers bash in detail. If you want to become a better shell scripter then you should read it.

Comment: If you stick around on the site I am sure you will get the rep soon :) thanks for accepting.